# PHP - Unset $_SESSION variables using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach, unset

Is it possible to unset `$_SESSION` variables using a `foreach` cycle? This is an example.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['one'] = 'one';
$_SESSION['two'] = 'two';
$_SESSION['three'] = 'three';
print_r($_SESSION);
foreach($_SESSION as $value) {
    unset($value);
}
session_destroy();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

I think that this script should work but it's not working for me. It gives me this output, without unsetting the variables :

> Array ( [one] => one [two] => two [three] => three )
> Array ( [one] =>
>   one [two] => two [three] => three )

Maybe it's a problem related to superglobal arrays. I can anyway unset the variables using their key :

```
unset($_SESSION['one']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must get the key and `unset` `$_SESSION[$key]` or pass your variable by reference (not sure if you can `unset` a reference).

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}

foreach($_SESSION as &$value) {
    unset($value);
}
```

Comment: The first solution is working, while the seconde one is not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable by reference :

```
foreach($_SESSION as &$value) {
    // edit $value
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me, but @Marwelln's one is.

Comment: you can use `session_unset` to unset all the sessions

Answer (score 0):

unset it with,

```
unset($_SESSION);
```

Comment: From php.net: *Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.*